# Cannot set Maui button background color

Tags: button, colors, background, maui

Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/985217/change-maui-button-background-color-at-runtime. I have experienced the same issue. Background works but not BackgroundColor. And also seems I cannot defined my own color from Brush for Background. The code below is run on Android Emulator API 30.
Any ideas? TIA.

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;

    if (count % 2 == 0)
        CounterBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0.3176471, 0.1686275, 0.8313726, 1); // works
    else
        CounterBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.FromUint(574049); // doesn't work

    if (count == 1)
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
    else
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

    SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
}
```

I found the reason. Color.FromUint(574049) makes alpha=0. If change to CounterBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0.03137255, 0.7607843, 0.3803922, 1) , it works.

Comment: What platform are you running into this problem on? I created a simple demo, click the button to change its background color and it can be displayed normally, can you provide some code that you encounter the problem for me to test?

Comment: Show us how you do those actions, so we can point you how to fix it. Right now the answer I can give you is "learn to do it right" from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/solidcolor?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: There is a known issue on GitHub: [Some properties not updating](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11662#issuecomment-1342789818). Is this similar to this thread?

Answer (score 0):

According to @WWW's update on the question, I have summarized the answer, hoping to help others with the same issue.

As @WWW said changing `Color.FromUint` to `Color.FromRgba` usage will work fine.

Comment: For me setting Background instead of BackgroundColor works as well. 
But what is weird that in Release build this happens, but in Debug build both Background and BacgroundColor works.